# Strip text with custom regex in python

Tags: python, regex, strip

```
(2, 43) 0.74670222994
(3, 15) 0.74132892839
(3, 31) 0.671141877647
(4, 19) 0.699490245832
(4, 47) 0.422715095257
(4, 48) 0.433278265941
(4, 0)  0.379862196713
(5, 19) 0.653731227092
(5, 72) 0.756726821729
```

Above is a tfidf matrix which has been written to a file.
I want to read only the tf-idf values like 0.74132892839 and append them to a list.

Is there a way to do f.read() and then strip the indices off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution using [***re.sub()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function:

```
import re

# specify your actual file name
with open('lines.txt', 'r') as fh:
    result = re.sub(r'\([^)]+\)\s*', '', fh.read()).split('\n')

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['0.74670222994', '0.74132892839', '0.671141877647', '0.699490245832', '0.422715095257', '0.433278265941', '0.379862196713', '0.653731227092', '0.756726821729']
```

---

`\([^)]+\)` - matches a sequence between parentheses